# Magnet substitution

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields

I wonder if the two magnet configurations below are equivalent. If they are not - what will be the effects on the flux?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nope! The first two large magnets in 1) have nonzero dipole moments, while in 2), the pairs of magnets have the magnetic dipole charge canceled. The right way to divide the large magnet with "S" at the top and "N" at the bottom is clearly to have two magnets with "S" at the top and "N" at the bottom! It doesn't matter whether these two half-magnets mutually attract or repel. The force has to be cancelled by attaching them mechanically etc. But the force they exert on other magnets is only the same if their orientations agree with the original magnet.

You may also see that by looking at the field lines. The lines always go from "S" to "N", or according to the convention you use. So in 1), they go from the top end of the magnet to the bottom end. In your 2), the field lines also go from the left side of the top to the right side of the top, and similarly at the bottom. The fields are clearly different.

Comment: so if I take two small magnets with S at the top and N on the bottom and superglue them together(or connect them in any other way) then I will have the same thing as one big magnet?

Comment: oh, yes, I read here about similar thing, seems logical
https://van.physics.illinois.edu/qa/listing.php?id=15533
Thanks! :)